# verifyIdToken without firebase-admin?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I would really like to use `Next.js`' [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextmiddleware) to validate requests. However, the `validateIdToken` method is only available in `firebase-admin` SDK, which needs to run on a NodeJS server, while Next.js edge runs on V8.

Is there some tutorial on how to verify tokens without using the `firebase-admin` SDK?

Comment: Are you looking for [Firebase Auth verify JWT ID Tokens without SDK with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987673/firebase-auth-verify-jwt-id-tokens-without-sdk-with-nodejs)?

Comment: #1 Are you working with 01 spa and  01 microservice or an all-in-one with next.js ? #2 Is your login based on google services? #3 What is your iam or how your JWT is created and validated?

Comment: Thanks @Dharmaraj, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @JRichardsz, I use client-side firebase JS library for auth, including creation of JWT.